# Symfony2 Cookies not being set in controller

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I can't seem to get cookies set from my controller.

code:

```
/**
     * @Route("", name="wx_exchange_default_index")
     * @Template("WXExchangeBundle:Default:index.html.twig")
     * @Method({"GET"})
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        $returnArray['parents'] = self::getCategories();
        $cookieLocationSession = $request->cookies->get('locationidsession', 0);
        $cookieLocation = $request->cookies->get('locationid', 0);
        $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
        $hashids = $this->get("wxexchange_hashids_service");

        if ($securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED'))
        {
            $user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
            $returnArray['user'] = $user;
            $location = $user->getTblProfile()->getTblLocation();

            if(!$cookieLocation || $cookieLocation != $hashids->encrypt($location->getId()))
            {
                $cookieLocation = $hashids->encrypt($location->getId());

                //TODO: cookies are not being set figure out whys
                $response = new Response();
                $response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie("locationid", $cookieLocation, 365, '/', null, false, false));
                $response->sendHeaders();
            }
        }

        if (!$cookieLocation && !$cookieLocationSession)
        {
            return $returnArray;
        }

        if ($cookieLocationSession)
        {
            $cookieLocation = $cookieLocationSession;
        }

        if (!isset($location) || $cookieLocationSession)
        {
            $locationService = $this->get("wxexchange_location_service");
            $locationId = $hashids->decrypt($cookieLocation);
            if(count($locationId) >= 1)
                $location = $locationService->getLocationById($locationId[0]);
        }

        if(isset($location))
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('wx_exchange_location', array('slug' => $location->getSlug(), 'locationid' => $cookieLocation)));


        return $returnArray;
    }
```

Do I have to return the response? If I do how do I keep processing (I have a redirect further down in my code)?

**Edit:** Interestingly enough if the same cookie is already set (via JQuery) running the code above deletes it, but it won't set it.

**Edit:** Action code posted.

Comment: Could you show your **`redirect`** code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, Sorry everyone.

It's my error.

In my javascript I'm using a Jquery cookie plugin and when you set a new cookie you tell it the number of days before expiry:

```
$.cookie('locationid', value, { expires: 365, path: '/' });
```

Unfortunately I used a part of this syntax in my controller:

```
$cookie = new Cookie("locationid", $cookieLocation, 365, '/', null, false, false);
```

The problem is the third parameter is supposed to be a DateTime so while I thought I was telling it to expire in 365 days I probably created a cookie that expired almost instantly after creation.

Thanks for all the answers and time spent on your part, this is why I love SO.

Answer (score 1):

The cookie object has httpOnly set to true by default, http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Cookie.html

This means that the browser should not make the cookie visible to client-side scripts.  If you need to see the cookie in your scripts you can pass the 7th parameter as false when you create the cookie.

```
$response->headers->setCookie(new Cookie('foo', 'bar',time() + 60, '/', null, false, false));
```

If you just need to view the cookie for debugging purposes you can use Chrome Dev tools.  They are available under the 'Resources' tab.

**Edit** : Try `$response->sendHeaders();`

Comment: Sorry that does not work, I'm using Firebug btw. I can create the cookie via JQuery but once that code I posted is run it deletes the cookie and if I refresh the page to run that code again it simply does not create the cookie.

Comment: Do you include use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Cookie; ?

Comment: @ClémentAndraud I tried your edit, but alas still no cookie. And yes I do include the Cookie class. I've posted my redirect code, but I'm not sure it will help (I hope it does).

Comment: @JohntheRipper I think your cookies are not set for the redirect function. Have you tried using `setVary()` after redirect function? [http://api.symfony.com/2.4/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/RedirectResponse.html#method_setVary] but before return you need to assign the redirected obj to a variable then `setVary(with cookies in header)` then return the object `$rdObj = $this->redirect(...); $rdObj->setVary(array(new cookies)); return $rdObj;`

Comment: I added my own answer since I figured this silly error out :s